# My program won't print anything...

Tags: c++, calculator

So I'm working on building a calculator that mimics the ones we use everyday. What I have shown is the logic within my function. 
Previously when I had my cout lines (deleted, not shown anymore) to see if my "y" was being correctly stores, and my two variables, finalNum1 & 2, everything was working, but when going back, trying to add new cout lines, nothing prints. If there are more issues, feel free to point them out, but this code is unfinished, my main concern is nothing is printing, I understand this code still needs work. If anyone can help that'd be greatly appreciated!

```
int Calculator::calculate()
{
    if (userInput[0] != 'q' || 'Q') // Checks for user input "Quit" or "quit"
    {

        int stringSize;
        std::cin >> userInput;      // User Input

        stringSize = userInput.length();
        int y = 0;
        while (y < stringSize)
        {
            if (isdigit(userInput[y]))
            {}
            else
            {
                posi = y;
            }
            y++;
        }
        first = userInput.substr(0,posi);
        second = userInput.substr(posi+1,y);
        finalNum1 = std::stoi(first);       // Sigbart error
        finalNum2 = std::stoi(second);
        std::cout << finalNum1 + finalNum2; // won't print 

        switch (userInput[posi])
        {
            case '+':
                std::cout << finalNum1 + finalNum2;
                break;

            case '-':
                std::cout << finalNum1 - finalNum2;
                break;

            case '*':
                std::cout << finalNum1 * finalNum2;
                break;

            case '/':
                std::cout << finalNum1 / finalNum2;
                break;

            case '%':
                std::cout << finalNum1 % finalNum2;
                break;
        }



    }

    else
        std::cout << "Goodbye";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code never verifies that `posi` is valid.

Comment: `if (userInput[0] != 'q' || 'Q')` should be changed to `if (userInput[0] != 'q' || userInput[0] != 'Q')`

Comment: There must be dup for this, but `(userInput[0] != 'q' || 'Q')` is wrong: `(userInput[0] != 'q' && userInput[0] != 'Q')` is what you are wanting.

Comment: @Dai in fact, `posi` is not even declared!

Comment: If you want it to print flush the stream like this: `std::cout << finalNum1 + finalNum2 << std::flush;`

Answer (score -1):

For printing integer it is easier if you cast them to string.

```
using namespace std;

float tmp = finalNumber1 + finalNumber2;
string out = to_string(tmp);
cout << tmp << endl;
```

Then another thing. You should use `for` instead of `while`.

Comment: This is a no-answer. How does it remotely address anything OP is asking?

Comment: That's how you can print integers or floats without any problems

Comment: Please tell me what will be the problem with how OP has done it?

Comment: If your implementation has trouble streaming a `float`, you have bigger problems... Also, please stop `using namespace std;`.